# Unable to iterate through JSON Array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I know this question has been asked many times but I stuck somewhere to fetch data everytime I am getting undefined variable. can someone please help to iterate through JSON data using jquery ajax.

```
[  
 {  
  "Orderdetails":[  
     {  
        "errorMsg":"success",
        "customername":"Walk In Customer",
        "grandtotal":"1496.00",
        "outletname":"Pradhan Ji Mobile",
        "paymentmethodname":"Cash",
        "customer_id":"1",
        "outlet_id":"13"
     }
  ]
},
{  
  "product":[  
     {  
        "product_name":"Tripr Printed Men V-neck Multicolor T-Shirt",
        "product_code":"5674664",
        "price":"374.00",
        "qty":"2"
     },
     {  
        "product_name":"Tripr Printed Men V-neck Multicolor T-Shirt",
        "product_code":"5674665",
        "price":"374.00",
        "qty":"1"
     },
     {  
        "product_name":"Tripr Printed Men V-neck Multicolor T-Shirt",
        "product_code":"5674666",
        "price":"374.00",
        "qty":"1"
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate"? What is your aim? What data do you wanna get?

Comment: I want to fetch customer_id first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you get is a list of 2 objects `Orderdetails` and `product` both containing another list. If you want to get the `customer_id`out of `Orderdetails` you can do it as follows.

```
// let's assume the list is called jsonList.

// Orderdetails is an element of the first list
const orderdetails = jsonList[0].Orderdetails;

// Then get the customer_id out of the first list in Orderdetails
const customer_id = Orderdetails[0].customer_id;
```

Or all this in a shorter way

```
const customer_id = jsonList[0].Orderdetails[0].customer_id;
```

> EDIT

If you want to iterate through `product` use `.forEach()`

```
// get the list product
const product = jsonList[0].product;

// iterate through it with forEach()
product.forEach( element => {

    // you now have access to the fields of each single element of the list
    console.log('product_name', element.product_name);
    console.log('product_code', element.product_code);

    // .. and so on

});
```

Comment: thanks!! can you please tell me how can iterate through product JSON Array using for loop

Comment: Sure. Just use the `forEach()`-loop. I edited my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

if you want fetch customer_id means, try `data[0].Orderdetails[0].customer_id`
where data will be JSON.